# Importing specific data from complex page data using ImportData function

Tags: google-apps-script, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on an ecommerce data importer that its main task to import product data and images using google spreadsheets.

Everything is fine except for the product image, Its passed dynamically to the page using JavaScript therefore it can't be scraped using google spreadsheet function.

After doing some researches I found out that the product images are returning when the ImportData function is applied to the product link.

The Importdata call is returning something like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H2mngLTY0M4cj33ldHh9EtXYX4FdQl-b1nidVQK3aaA/edit?usp=sharing).

As you can see it is very wide return that it has to be transposed and I have to add columns too to make it fit at one sheet.

You can see the pieces of information I need in the "GO" column .. It is repeated about 14 times. the first time is at GO169

My final goal is to get the Product images for each product concatenated in one cell and separated by a comma.

My Question is, is there is an importxml function query that would return the elements which are followed by the (image:[") thing or even the (@type:"Product") which you can see at the (GO157) cell.

Or any ideas how to achieve My goal would be much appreciated.

Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your expected situation. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: Hello Tanaike
My expected output shall be the links which are in (column GO) Cell Number 169,170,171 only ( which are links to the product image) without the rest of the page data

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the following values from the URL of `https://www.zara.com/tr/en/windowpane-check-shirt-p03182668.html?v1=96230160&v2=1676978`.

  ```
    https://static.zara.net/photos///2021/V/0/3/p/3182/668/802/2/w/1920/3182668802_6_1_1.jpg?ts=1615888138279
    https://static.zara.net/photos///2021/V/0/3/p/3182/668/802/2/w/1920/3182668802_6_2_1.jpg?ts=1615888208926
    https://static.zara.net/photos///2021/V/0/3/p/3182/668/802/2/w/1920/3182668802_6_3_1.jpg?ts=1615888190335
  ```

When I saw the HTML of the URL, I confirmed that the values are included in the JSON object. In this case, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using the custom function created by Google Apps Script. Because when Google Apps Script is used, JSON object can be simply parsed using `JSON.parse()`. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and save it.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  const value = [...res.getContentText().matchAll(/<script type\="application\/ld\+json">([\w\s\S]+?)<\/script>/g)];
  if (!value || value.length == 0) throw new Error("Values cannot be retrieved.");
  const obj = JSON.parse(value[0][1]);
  return obj[0].image;
}
```

- When you use this script, please put `=SAMPLE("https://www.zara.com/tr/en/windowpane-check-shirt-p03182668.html?v1=96230160&v2=1676978")` to a cell. By this, the custom function is run with the URL.
- From your expected values, I confirmed that the values are the 1st element of the array.

#### Result:

When above script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for the URL of `https://www.zara.com/tr/en/windowpane-check-shirt-p03182668.html?v1=96230160&v2=1676978`. So when you use other URLs, the script might not be able to be used. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Hello Again Tanaike
Thank You so much for your help it brilliantly works.
I have a related question. How can I access the json object of a url, I mean is there is a way to get all the available json keys? Or how did you assume the existance of the links in image object. Thanks

Comment: @mostafam123g About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, about your new question, I cannot understand about what you want to do. So can I ask you about the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Thank You So much for getting back to me.
My question in clear form is: 
You said in your answer " When I saw the HTML of the URL, I confirmed that the values are included in the JSON object" 
The Question: How to know the keys which are included in the JSON Object of a web page?
how to see the keys and values related to it? 
example input : URL 
example output: json object keys are = 1. Name = x 
2. Price = y 
3. z = t 
etc..

Comment: @mostafam123g Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your new question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon. Can you give me a time to understand about your new question?